# Electric stand up scooter repair of foam filled solid tire

Tags: electrical, tires, scooter

[image: Rear foam-filled tire with hole]

Vehicle: eco reco L5+ stand up electric scooter, max spd 20mph https://ecorecoscooter.com/product/l5/

Tire picked up a 3/4" long sheet metal screw. Now as the picture shows, there's a solid foam-filled ftire on this scooter with a hole in it.

Multiple tire shops in and around Portland Oregon can't fix it, and although I can run with the rear tire with that hole in it, filling in the hole will lengthen the tire's remaining life.

What could I use to fill in that hole so the tire lasts longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would shove a tire plug into it and move on. Since the tire is foam filled, it doesn't have to be air tight and this isn't a street legal vehicle going down the highway. It is possible that the tire will start to seperate, but that should be noticeable when riding.

Comment: Plug kit acquired from local auto parts store. Works.

Answer (score 1):

“Remaining life”... Personally I would go for a new one in terms of my safety...

The question is why won’t the repair shops do it : answer : because the damage to the plies means there is a high risk of failure ie safety...

As it is foam -filled then it will be difficult, if not impossible, to remove the tire to be able to repair it from behind - again leading to replace it...

Your choice but best option is replacement.

Comment: The only way I’ve seen foam filled tires come off is with a sawz-all. I’ve never had the pleasure to do one myself. @k7aay Tire looks like it’s shot anyways. I doubt it’d pass a safety inspection if they do that where you live.